# Android: R cannot be resolved to a variable after changing sdk path

Tags: android

The sdk folder was too big and I needed to move it. So I did. The problem is now that my projects have the following error:  `R cannot be resolved to a variable.`

Also when I click on the sdk button an error occurs: `Failed to run Android SDK Manager. Check the Android Console View for details.` But nothing is shown in the console.

I'm using Eclipse on Linux Mint.

Do you know how to fix this?

**EDIT**

Maybe the problem comes that I moved the android-sdk folder from an ext partition to NTFS. Now I am unable to execute the android.

Comment: just delete all the errors on Problems and do clean and build

Comment: Sadly it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the new path of the SDK on Eclipse using Window -> Preferences -> Android

Comment: Try going to your SDK folder using the Terminal and execute the manager `{sdk-path}/tools/android` maybe its a file system permission problem

Comment: Yes, maybe it is. I saw that the files aren't marked as executable and I can't mark them. Maybe the problem comes from that I moved the android folder to an NTFS file system.

Comment: I bet it is... try moving them back to your ext partition